# How to find where promotion applies according to base price or total price?

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud, promotions

I could not handle a case related to new promotion engine in Hybris. I just want to learn where promotions apply according to base price or base price with taxes. I have a case which product promotion applies according to base price (net price) and cart promotion applies according to base price with taxes(total price). I investigated RAO's but I have no solution. I just thought that it is necessary to customize drools rule engine but it might be so cumbersome.

How to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend **DefaultCalculationService** for manipulating calculation. Also delivery cost included to total for cart promotion. You can override **calculateTotals**, **calculateTotalTaxValues**, **resetAdditionalCosts** methods in this service.